# Laravel - pagination and orderBy not working

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, sql-order-by

I ordered my cars posts with created_at and paginate it but it doesn't work.Here is my code:
`CarsController@index`:

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $cars = Car::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(3);
        return view('cars.index')->with('cars', $cars);
    }
```

After this and `{{$cars->links()}}` in my `index.blade.php` it shows me this error: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View: C:\engineering\xampp\htdocs\carapp\resources\views\cars\index.blade.php)`

And if I remove `->paginate(3);` and replace it with `->get();` it also not working for `orderBy`. Why is this happening? My laravel version is 5.8

Comment: Have you tried like: `return view('cars.index', compact('cars'))`?

Comment: @mare96 I just tried but nothing happen

Comment: Can you `dd($cars);` before return and provide what you get?

Comment: @mare96 when I ```dd($cars)``` before return nothing happen.. strange....

Comment: @mare96 When I do it on my other page for motorbikes it give me array of my motorbikes, but on cars page stay the same

Comment: Are you sure that you are pointing a good route? To check do some `dd(1);` to see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210554/discussion-between-mare96-and-milos).

Comment: @mare96 I just fixed ```orderBy``` problem, it works just fine now. It was a problem in another controller. Can you please help me with paginate problem? With error: ```Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View: C:\engineering\xampp\htdocs\carapp\resources\views\cars\index.blade.php)``` when i put ```{{$cars->links()}}``` in my blade ?

Comment: Can you join in the discussion?

Comment: plz post `dd(get_class($cars))`, and what's your laravel version?